# POP3 on Gmail doesn't retrieve spam email from outlook

Tags: email, microsoft-outlook, gmail, spam-prevention, pop3

I have pop3 on Gmail but it retrieves emails from outlook only from inbox folder but not from the spam folder. Is there a way pop3 to sent the spam emails (which some of them are not spam) to my Gmail?

Comment: While not about your question directly, just an FYI that Webmail should only be used as a last resort because it's insecure with few safeguards against the host machine being exploited. A desktop email client is the recommended and safest way to view emails, with multiple free versions existing across OS platforms _(if using Android, neither the Gmail or Outlook app will filter all phishing emails, whereas desktop clients usually are able to do so with a high degree of accuracy, sending them to the Junk/Spam folder)_

Answer (score 0):

If your client uses POP3 and you still want to do server side spam filtering, don't move spam to Junk. Keep it in inbox and use tagging instead. Make a proper Outlook config so good e-mail don't end-up there.

POP3 users can set filters in their email programs and move all messages with *SPAM* or *JUNK* tag to their Junk folders.

POP3 protocol does not support folders. If you want multiple folders, you use IMAP or you filter things on client-side.

Answer (score 0):

As I know, in Outlook desktop client, it is by design that Outlook search will not include items in your Junk Email folder, not only for POP accounts but also for all the email accounts. And if you do not want specific emails goes into junk email folder, you might need to configure your Junk email options and add senders to safe sender list. [Overview of the Junk Email Filter](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/overview-of-the-junk-email-filter-5ae3ea8e-cf41-4fa0-b02a-3b96e21de089)